# Industry standard for outdoor appliance AC input bulkhead connector

Tags: ac, connector, outdoors

I am looking to spec an AC input receptacle that is appropriate for outdoor use.  The equipment for which it is required is essentially a relocatable enclosure that is designed to operate unattended for long periods of time.

On first thought [IEC 60320 C13/14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_320#C13.2FC14_coupler) style AC input modules seem appealing as adapter cables are readily available for input up to 250V.  Our equipment can accept a range of voltages so this would allow simple in field customization. In our application the bulkhead fitting should be at least IP65/66 in terms of ingress protection to the equipment.  However there seems to be a complete lack of outdoor appropriate power input modules for this requirement. [Example search](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv801=296&pv801=264&pv801=287&FV=fff40016%2Cfff803b7&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=25142&fid=0&pageSize=25). This leads me to believe there may be another standard that is more widely adopted.

There are obviously many connector systems that will solve this problem (Amphenol/LEMO/Bulgin) though none appear to adhere to a single standard. Captivating a power cord, while easier, does not allow for flexible configuration in terms of input voltages.

My question is what is the general industry standard for outdoor appliances/equipment that will support multiple input voltages?  Does one exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not [IP67 rated](https://www.google.com/search?q=IEC+60309+IP65+OR+IP66+OR+IP67&tbm=shop) [IEC 60309](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309)?

[image]
IP44 250 VAC outlet and line-plug <sub>(see later for IP67 examples)</sub>
<sup>*[image©sjs77](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CEE_3P%2BN%2BPE_230V.jpg)*</sup>

> IEC 60309 (formerly IEC 309) is an international standard from the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) for "plugs, socket-outlets and couplers for industrial purposes".

...

> The colour of an IEC 60309 plug or socket indicates its voltage and frequency rating. The most widespread colours are yellow 125 V, blue 250 V and red 400 V. The black 500 V version can often be found on ships.

[image]
[image]
IP67 400VAC inlet and line-socket

[image]
[image]
IP67 120VAC inlet and line-socket.

<sup>*(images from [InternationalConfig](http://internationalconfig.com/icc5.asp?productgroup='IEC%2060309%20(309)%20Wiring%20Devices%20and%20Cord%20Sets'))*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have found is this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1772